# click button crashing when click android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a form that includes students details and again show that detail in text views. When the user types the details in edit texts save them into the model class then show them again in text views. first, I have created a model class to save variables of students.

Logcat:

```
2021-11-09 13:12:47.784 30040-30040/com.example.studentapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.studentapp, PID: 30040
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "stephen"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
    at com.example.studentapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

XML file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"

        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Age"

        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_grade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Grade"

        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Address"

         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Distance"

         />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGrade"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDistance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
        
        <Button
            android:text="View"
            
            android:id="@+id/btnView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Model class:

```java
package com.example.studentapp;
   public class Student {
   public String name = "";
   public int age = 0;
   public int grade = 0;
   public String address = "";
   public double distance = 0;
}
```

This is .java file:

```java
package com.example.studentapp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonView;
EditText editName;
EditText editAge;
EditText editGrade;
EditText editAddress;
EditText editDistance;

TextView textName, textAge, textGrade, textAddress, textDistance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editName = findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    editAge = findViewById(R.id.edit_age);
    editGrade = findViewById(R.id.edit_grade);
    editAddress = findViewById(R.id.edit_address);
    editDistance = findViewById(R.id.edit_distance);

    textName = findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    textAge = findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
    textGrade = findViewById(R.id.txtGrade);
    textAddress = findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    textDistance = findViewById(R.id.txtDistance);

    buttonView = findViewById(R.id.btnView);

    buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Student student1 = new Student();
            student1.name = editName.getText().toString();
            student1.age = Integer.parseInt(editAge.getText().toString());
            student1.grade = Integer.parseInt( editName.getText().toString());
            student1.address = editName.getText().toString();
            student1.distance = Double.parseDouble( editName.getText().toString());

            textName.setText(student1.name);
            textAge.setText(""+student1.age);
            textGrade.setText(student1.grade+" Years");
            textAddress.setText(student1.address);
            textDistance.setText(student1.distance+"km");

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Please, bear in mind that I am a very beginner at android development.

Comment: Please share the crash log. It will help to identify the problem

Comment: hii , pls can you tell me how to find the crash log? Thank you for ur help

Comment: How to analyze stack trace: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: I edit the question and attach the logcat error pls help me guys...

Comment: add inputType="number" in edittext: age, grade or distance, so its take numbers only

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "stephen"`

Comment: Your'e trying to make stephan as double ... and it's imposible

Answer (score 2):

```
student1.distance = Double.parseDouble(editName.getText().toString());
```

You are using `editName` for getting distance grade and address. Please, change them according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
student1.grade = Integer.parseInt( editName.getText().toString());
student1.distance = Double.parseDouble( editName.getText().toString());
```

Expected code

```
student1.grade = Integer.parseInt( editGrade.getText().toString());
student1.distance = Double.parseDouble( editDistance.getText().toString());
```

Your are trying to parse string to integer `Integer.parseInt( editName.getText().toString())`. It won't work for non numbers input.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at your Locat message, it seems you're saving the String name in an Integer variable, kindly look at your codebase to see if you're making that mistake, if so reassign the name variable to a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong editText for grade and distance.

your code:

```
student1.grade = Integer.parseInt(editName.getText().toString());
```

change **editName** to **editGrade** :

```
student1.grade = Integer.parseInt(editGrade.getText().toString());
```

aswell for:

```
student1.distance = Double.parseDouble(editName.getText().toString());
```

change **editName** to **editDistance**:

```
student1.distance = Double.parseDouble(editDistance.getText().toString());
```